# SQlite database creation?

Tags: android

```
public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

// Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";
```

can any one pls explain what above line doing .Am new to android.Is TABLE_COMMENT a column in table that we are creating?Why we have used "("?

Comment: This is more of a SQL question than an Android specific one.

Comment: its a table's name and COLUMN_ID and COLUMN_COMMENT  are columns..

Comment: You should have a look into the SQLite documentation http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: If you are new to Android-Sqlite ...try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Sample code: http://sdrv.ms/N857Wn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TABLE_COMMENTS: name of table.

COLUMN_ID: Name of a auto increment ID field.

COLUMN_COMMENT: comment, name of a textfield column in the table

Why you have used"("? Because that is the syntax

Answer (score 0):

`TABLE_COMMENTS` is name of your table  which resolves to `comments`!

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";
```

The complete query would become

```
create table comments (
      id integer primary key autoincrement, 
      comment text not null
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

The TABLE_COMMENTS is a table named: `comments`.

The COLUMN_ID and COLUMN_COMENT are columns.

The `"("` is to open the Table preferences, the code does: `Create a table > (inside the brackets it creates the columns.)`